# A C++ library used in multiple compilational units causes linker errors

Tags: c++, xcode, clang

I've been working on a larger project and stumbled onto a problem when refactoring it into multiple compilational units from its previous state of having only one.
Each one of the compilational units includes a custom library that it needs and they all compile normally, but when Xcode is trying to link then, the linker throws out a lot of duplicate symbol errors.

The library is composed of multiple files too, some of which require each other. Here's the example of how the library file is written.

File 1:

```
// lib.hpp
#ifndef LIB1_HPP_
#define LIB1_HPP_

namespace lib1
{
    class Class1
    {
        void foo (int a);
    }
}
#endif
```

File 2:

```
// lib.cpp

#include "lib.hpp"

lib1::Class1:foo (int a)
{
    return ...;
}
```

The only files included are the .hpp files, .cpp files are compiled with `-c` and added to the project in Xcode.

The error mentioned is (changed function names to match the ones in this post):

```
duplicate symbol __ZN5lib13Class5_fooE in:
/Users/---/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-haivawxacqnzswdyqtfrxlrqlakt/Build/Intermediates/Project.build/Debug/Project.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/file.o
```

The error appears multiple times as there are multiple functions in the library, but it's always the same thing.

Comment: Can you include the full link error in your post?

Comment: Are you sure that your files don't try to define `foo` as well, and that `lib.hpp` doesn't contain an out-of-line definition of it?

Comment: @Angew I'm sure, especially since all of the functions in a library are in a namespace.

Comment: could you add your compilation commands (-c & obj linking)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a problem with me incorrectly using extern. I've fixed it a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
#pragma once
```

or

```
#ifndef Class1_h
#define Class1_h

... your declarations ...

#endif
```